# External access for domain users

Tags: 2013

I have been trawling Google for some time and am failing to find an answer to my question:

What's the best way to allow users to access my entire SharePoint 2013 site/farm from outside of our corporate network??

Is it really as simple as pointing the firewall to port 443 of the WFE?

UAG seems to be on the way out and I don't want to use the publishing features...HELP!

Answer (score 0):

For external access I would suggest using identity provider with SAML authentication.

> ## SAML token-based authentication
>
> SAML token-based authentication in SharePoint 2013 uses the SAML 1.1 protocol and the WS-Federation Passive Requestor Profile (WS-F PRP). It requires coordination with administrators of a claims-based environment, whether it is your own internal environment or a partner environment. If you use Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) 2.0, you have a SAML token-based authentication environment.
>
> A SAML token-based authentication environment includes an identity provider security token service (IP-STS). The IP-STS issues SAML tokens on behalf of users whose accounts are included in the associated authentication provider. Tokens can include any number of claims about a user, such as a user name and the groups to which the user belongs. An AD FS 2.0 server is an example of an IP-STS.
>
> SharePoint 2013 takes advantage of claims that are included in tokens that an IP-STS issues to authorized users. In claims environments, an application that accepts SAML tokens is known as a relying party STS (RP-STS). A relying party application receives the SAML token and uses the claims inside to decide whether to grant the client access to the requested resource. In SharePoint 2013, each web application that is configured to use a SAML provider is added to the IP-STS server as a separate RP-STS entry. A SharePoint farm can represent multiple RP-STS entries in the IP-STS.

[image]

Reference: [Plan for SAML token-based authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#plansaml)

More to read: [Design Sample: Extranet with Dedicated Zones for Authentication for SharePoint 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30368)

Comment: Benny, please don't post duplicate answers. In this case it looks like the question is a dupe, so I have closed this one. Thanks.

Comment: @SPDoctor OK, I won't. Next time I'll flag as duplicate instead. Alright?

Comment: Yes, I think that is a better plan if the questions are duplicates, which is usually the case when the answer is the same.